# samsung orsay toast build doesnt open on tv (2011)

Tags: cordova-plugins, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

i have the following problem: i have created an app with toast(cordova) and want to test it on the old samsung tv. If I upload it to a http server and download it via the tv with the developer account the following error message appears.

Failed to install. For more information, visit
http://www.samsungdforum.com/Support/TVAppsSecurity

the app cannot be installed on the tv
does anyone have a solution?